# Memory leak in SDL2

Tags: sdl-2

I'm trying to solve this one but I am stumped. When I continuously hover over an object, the ram usage increases. The hover code is below:

```
//Small memory leak here. Need to figure this out.
void PlayerInteraction::InteractionControllerHover(std::string interactionMessage) {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(Scene1::ftexture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(Scene1::fsurface);
    const char* im = interactionMessage.c_str();
    if (interactionMessage != "" ) {
        int interactionMessagelength = interactionMessage.length();
        Scene1::textRect = { 500, 610, interactionMessagelength * 10, 20 };   
        Scene1::fsurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Scene1::font, im, Scene1::fcolor);
        Scene1::ftexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Scene1::renderer, Scene1::fsurface); 
       //_sleep(70) seems to slow the leak down.
    }
 }
```

if I add _sleep(70) to the code, the memory leak is much slower, however I can't figure out why its leaking because I am destroying the texture each time the hover occurs. I don't like adding sleep because it causes other issues. Any advice?

[image]

```
            //Mouse Hover Game Interaction.
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:      
                    //Event Motion coordinates. Where the mouse moves on the screen.
                    x = event.motion.x;
                    y = event.motion.y;
                    gd = gdSprite.x;
                    gy = gdSprite.y;

                    //This addresses the movement to the left issue where the player never reaches to destination and prevents hover interaction.
                    if (playerMessage != true && interactionMessage == "") { 
                        //Prevents sleep from kicking in when walking to a target.
                        if (gdSprite.x < gd && gdSprite.y < y || gdSprite.x > gd && gdSprite.y > y) {
                            ftexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, fsurface); //Potentially fixes sprite appearing in text.
                            SDL_DestroyTexture(ftexture);
                            playerIsMoving = 0; 
                        }
                       
                        else {                         
                            ftexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,fsurface); //Potentially fixes sprite appearing in text.
                            SDL_DestroyTexture(ftexture);
                            SDL_DestroyTexture(Textures::spriteTexture);
                            Textures::spriteTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Textures::spriteDown1); //Makes player face you when you are hovering.
                        }
                               
                        interactionMessage = pob.HoverObjects(x, y, scene, gd, gy);
                      
                    }
                    if (interactionMessage != "" && playerIsMoving !=1) {
                        _sleep(70); //reduces memory leak when repeatedly hovering over objects in quick succession.
                        pi.InteractionControllerHover(interactionMessage);                        
                      
                    }                 

                    break;                    
                
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    case SDLK_q:
                    gameover = 1;
                    break;
                }
                break;          
            }
            
    }
```

[image]

Comment: In first code snippet you seem to leak `fsurface` as it doesn't look you free old surface anywhere. As for second snippet, I don't even know what to think - why you create texture and immediately destroy it, in at least two places? Where `fsurface` data comes from? Could you describe what you think this code is supposed to do?

Comment: For some reason, and I don't know why but the reason I create the texture and immediately destroy it is because it seems to prevent the player sprite from randomly appearing in the text box (I don't know why it it fixes it but it does)

Comment: As for what the code is doing: When I hover the mouse over an object the Interaction message gets the returned value from the pob.hoverobjects and then if there is a value returned, the pi.InteractionControllerHover then displays the text rect. As far as I see, it works very well (except for this hover leak annoyance).

Comment: The line of code that triggers the memory leak is:  Scene1::fsurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Scene1::font, im, Scene1::fcolor);

Comment: @MrTea that's what I said. Every allocation needs to have release somewhere. If you create SDL surface, you need to release it with `SDL_FreeSurface` when you no longer need it. Once you've created texture from surface you probably no longer need that surface and could free it immediately, but only you know if that's the case. If you use this surface anywhere else then that's obviously not the case.

Comment: Hi Keltar, thank you for your help. I tried adding the SDL_FreeSurface(fsurface) but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm quite stuck on this one. I'll keep trying though, its actually quite fun to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. This seems to have fixed the problem:

```
void PlayerInteraction::InteractionControllerHover(std::string interactionMessage) {

const char* im = interactionMessage.c_str();
if (interactionMessage != "" ) {
    int interactionMessagelength = interactionMessage.length();
    Scene1::textRect = { 500, 610, interactionMessagelength * 10, 20 };   // The * 10, 20 is a mathematical way of setting the text width depending on the length of the text.
    Scene1::fsurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Scene1::font, im, Scene1::fcolor);
    Scene1::ftexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Scene1::renderer, Scene1::fsurface);     
    SDL_FreeSurface(Scene1::fsurface);
  
}

     //Mouse Hover Game Interaction.
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:      
                    //Event Motion coordinates. Where the mouse moves on the screen.
                    x = event.motion.x;
                    y = event.motion.y;
                    gd = gdSprite.x;
                    gy = gdSprite.y;
                
                    //This addresses the movement to the left issue where the player never reaches to destination and prevents hover interaction.
                    if (playerMessage != true && interactionMessage == "") {                          
                        //Prevents sleep from kicking in when walking to a target.
                        if (gdSprite.x < gd && gdSprite.y < y || gdSprite.x > gd && gdSprite.y > y) {
                            SDL_DestroyTexture(ftexture);
                            playerIsMoving = 0;                           
                        }
                       
                        else {                               
                            SDL_DestroyTexture(ftexture);
                            SDL_DestroyTexture(Textures::spriteTexture);
                            Textures::spriteTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Textures::spriteDown1); //Makes player face you when you are hovering.
                        }
                      
                            interactionMessage = pob.HoverObjects(x, y, scene, gd, gy);   
                       
                    }

                    if (interactionMessage != "" && playerIsMoving !=1) {                                           
                        pi.InteractionControllerHover(interactionMessage);
                    }                 

                    break;                    
                
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    case SDLK_q:
                    gameover = 1;
                    break;
                }
                break;          
            }
            
    }
```